# java.text.ParseException while trying to parse a date in java

Tags: java, date, apache-commons, datetime-format

I can not parse the string "16 Apr 2014 17:00" as a string. I've trying to use `DateUtils` in `apachecommons` library. here is the test code with the exception

```
package com.buraktas;

import java.text.ParseException;
import java.util.Date;

import org.apache.commons.lang3.time.DateUtils;
import org.junit.Test;

public class ParseDateTest {

    @Test
    public void test() throws ParseException {

        String date = "18 Apr 2014 20:00";
        Date parseDate = DateUtils.parseDate(date, "dd MMM yyyy HH:mm");

        System.out.println(parseDate);
    }
}
```

and the stacktrace is like below;

```
java.text.ParseException: Unable to parse the date: 18 Apr 2014 20:00
    at org.apache.commons.lang3.time.DateUtils.parseDateWithLeniency(DateUtils.java:391)
    at org.apache.commons.lang3.time.DateUtils.parseDate(DateUtils.java:291)
    at org.apache.commons.lang3.time.DateUtils.parseDate(DateUtils.java:268)
    at com.buraktas.ParseDateTest.test(ParseDateTest.java:15)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

EDIT: The thing is I have to setup default locale to en_US even my JVM shows that my default is en _US. Here is the code.

```
@Test
public void testParse2() throws Exception {

    System.out.println(Locale.getDefault());

    String date = "18 Apr 2014 20:00";
    Locale.setDefault(Locale.ENGLISH);

    Date parseDate = DateUtils.parseDate(date, new String[] { "dd MMM yyyy HH:mm" });
    System.out.println(parseDate);

}
```

and the output is

```
en_US
Fri Apr 18 20:00:00 EEST 2014
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From your profile, it seems you are in Turkey. As such, if `parseDate` uses the default `Locale`, it may be using a Turkish `Locale`. `Apr` is not a shorthand for the Turkish word for that month.

Consider using your own `SimpleDateFormat` where you can set an English `Locale` (unless `DateUtils` has such a method).

Otherwise, try parsing a date with the Turkish (shorthand) word for April.

Inspecting the source, I can't find anything wrong. Please try

```
String date = "18 Apr 2014 20:00";
Locale.setDefault(Locale.US);

Date parseDate = DateUtils.parseDate(date, new String[] { "dd MMM yyyy HH:mm" });
System.out.println(parseDate);
```

Comment: this is one wicked way to answer :) +1

Comment: thanks for your answer, however, `Locale.getDefault()` gives `en_US` so there shouldn't be a problem about Locale ?

Comment: @quartaela No, you shouldn't have a problem with that I don't think. I'll delete and investigate further

Comment: @quartaela Try setting the default `Locale` right before. I can't reproduce your issue.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis finally! I thought that sending a format as a string rather than an array will be same. Anyway, works perfect! thanks a lot : ) Only thing that I don't get is default Locale shows en_US so why I should set it again to en_US ?

Comment: @quartaela The array really shouldn't be the issue though. The method is defined with varargs.

Comment: @quartaela The `Locale` was just me being thorough. Can you edit your question and show a test that displays the default `Locale` and the results?

Comment: @quartaela One last thing because I'm kind of out of ideas, what is the output of `Locale.getDefault(Locale.Category.FORMAT)`? Same thing?

Comment: I guess you got it. It gives tr_TR

Comment: @quartaela Yeah, turns out `SimpleDateFormat` uses that instead of the `getDefault()` method. Setting the `Locale` may set it for all categories. Yeah, I just checked. It does.

Comment: I got it now :). Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Your test runs for me. What version of commons-lang are you using? I'm using:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.1</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
```

on this JDK:

```
thor ~ $ java -version
java version "1.7.0_51"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_51-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.51-b03, mixed mode)
```

Comment: mine is `<dependency><groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId><artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId><version>3.3.1</version></dependency>`