# How to parse ddMMMyyyy with Java?

Tags: java, date, format

I'm trying to parse dates with the format ddMMMyyyy and convert them to dd.MM.YYYY. Sometimes my input String is as follows: 3Mar2014 or 1Jan2014 but i guess, this should not be a problem with the format ddMMMyyyy.

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMMyyyy");
    SimpleDateFormat convert = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy");
    String to = "";

    Date date;
    try
    {
        date = formatter.parse(from);
        to = convert.format(date);
    }
    catch (ParseException e)
    {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage() + " --- " + from);
    }
```

My code is always saying:

```
Unparseable date: "3Mar2014" --- 3Mar2014
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Changed it to Mar to avoid confusions

Comment: Check your `Locale`. It might not be an English language one.

Comment: It's working in Java 8. What version are you testing with?

Comment: I'm using java version "1.6.0_65"

Comment: It runs fine here; http://ideone.com/Wz83cV

Comment: @PeterLawrey It's the parsing that doesn't work, not the formatting. (BTW on ideone it works fine, because of the locale)

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis you should make that an answer.

Comment: @JBNizet I'd prefer confirmation. And then there are [duplicates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23118817/java-text-parseexception-while-trying-to-parse-a-date-in-java) if that's the case.

Comment: Yep works with setting the Locale to "en", "US".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the Locale to an english language one e.g.

```
Locale usLocale = new Locale("en", "US");
Locale.setDefault(usLocale);
```

solved the problem.

Changing the pattern to 'dMMMyyyy' without changing the Locale does not solve the problem. It's then still saying

```
Unparseable date: "5Oct2014"
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is with the pattern.

if you use "dMMMyyyy" instead, it works like a charm

Comment: Correct answer. But Locale should be added as well, to avoid depending implicitly on the JVM's current default locale which could vary.